# In iOS6, trouble forcing ViewController to certain interfaceOrientation when pushed on stack

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I have the following view controller set up:

viewController1 is able rotate freely to any orientation except portrait upside down.

viewController2 gets pushed on top of viewController1, and I'd like for it to be the same orientation viewController1 is and I'd like for it not to be able to rotate.

viewController3 gets pushed on top of viewController2. I'd like for viewController3 to be in portrait mode.

I'm having a lot of issues trying to accomplish this in iOS6 (haven't tried yet in iOS5). First off, I have already created my own Navigation Controller and put the following in it:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return [self.topViewController preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate
{
    return [self.topViewController shouldAutorotate];
}
```

I've tried a lot of different combinations of these things to know avail. Mainly where I'm struggling is forcing vc3 to be presented as portrait if vc2 is in landscape. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you're trying to do here is fighting the framework. What you're describing is simply not how a navigation controller architecture works in iOS 6. If you want to show a view controller's view and force rotation, use a presented view controller. That's the only time `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` is meaningful, and your view controller's `supportedInterfaceOrientations` will actually be consulted because, being presented, it will be at the root of the interface.

Comment: So do you mean I have to push it as a modalview in order to force its rotation? I can't push it on the navigational stack and force it?

Comment: Yes, exactly, except for the way you said it: you have to *present* it as what used to be called a modal view controller, not *push* it onto a navigation stack. A presented view controller can force rotation. A view controller pushed onto a navigation stack cannot; the app can decide dynamically how to respond when the *user rotates the device*, but the mere act of pushing the view controller onto the navigation stack won't cause the app interface to rotate.

Comment: Do you happen to know if there is a manual way to force the view controller to rotate after its presented? Like instead of the user to rotating it, telling it to rotate on its own?

Comment: You're just making me repeat myself. No, there isn't. The framework will rotate the app compensatorily if the *user* rotates the *device* and if the app, app delegate, and root view controller support it; and it will *force* rotation of the app in response to a view controller being presented. Otherwise it will do nothing.

Comment: Simply Awesome. Can someone put a link to the official explanation of this? I struggled for far too long with this.

Answer (score 5):

I have explained in a different answer that it is not supported, in iOS 6, to *force* rotation when pushing a new view controller on to a navigation controller. You can structure rules about *compensatory* rotation (i.e. what should happen if the user rotates the *device*), but you can't *force* the interface to rotate. The only situation in which iOS 6 is happy to let you *force* rotation is when presenting or dismissing a view controller (`presentViewController:animated:` and `dismissViewControllerAnimated:`).

However, it is possible to use a presented view controller in such a way that it kind of *looks* like you're pushing onto the navigation controller. I've made a movie showing what I mean:

http://youtu.be/O76d6FhPXlE

Now, that's not totally perfect by any means. There is no rotation animation of the status bar, and there is a kind of black "blink" between the two views - which is intentional, because it's there to cover up what is *really* going. What's really going on is that there are really *two* difference navigation controllers and *three* view controllers, as shown in this screen shot of the storyboard.

[image]

What we have is:

- a nav controller subclass set to portrait orientation, and its root view controller
- a second nav controller subclass set to landscape orientation, and its root view controller, which is black and functions as an intermediary
- a third view controller to be pushed onto the second nav controller's stack

When the user asks to go "forward" from the first view controller, we *present* the second navigation controller, thus seeing the black view controller momentarily, but then we immediately *push* the third view controller. So we get forced rotation, along with a kind of black flash and a push animation. When the user taps the Back button in the third view controller, we reverse the process.

All the transitional code is in the black view controller (ViewControllerIntermediary). I've tried to tweak it to give the most satisfying animation I can:

```
@implementation ViewControllerIntermediary {
    BOOL _comingBack;
}

- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationController.delegate = self;
}

-(void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)nc 
        willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)vc 
        animated:(BOOL)anim {
    if (self == vc)
        [nc setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:_comingBack];
    else
        [nc setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    if (!_comingBack) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushme" sender:self];
        _comingBack = YES;
    }
    else
        [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES 
            completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
if ([self.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController isKindOfClass: [SecondViewController class]])
{
    SecondViewController *secondController = (SecondViewController *) self.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController;

    if (secondController.isPresented)
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    else return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
else return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

And for Swift

```
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow) -> Int {

    if self.window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController? is SecondViewController {

        let secondController = self.window!.rootViewController.presentedViewController as SecondViewController

        if secondController.isPresented {
            return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All.toRaw());
        } else {
            return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.toRaw());
        }
    } else {
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.toRaw());
    }

}
```

For more details check this [link](http://swiftiostutorials.com/ios-orientations-landscape-orientation-one-view-controller/)