# View won't rotate after Navigation Controller is embedded

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I started a sample project and added the following code to my view controller. After launch the screen will be on landscape. 
Then I went to my Storyboard, clicked on my only view, -> editor -> embed in -> Navigation Controller. Launch the program again: the screen will be on portrait and won't change to landscape no matter what I try. Why is that? (All orientations are enabled in my plist.)

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 6, the rule is that once you are in a UINavigationController, the `supportedInterfaceOrientations` of *this* view controller (ViewController) are irrelevant. The only things consulted are:

- The app (Info.plist).
- The app delegate (`application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:`)
- The root view controller, which in your case is now the UINavigationController

Now, I do not entirely understand why your UINavigationController is giving you a portrait-only result. But I do know that if you want to *control* what the UINavigationController does about rotation, you will have to subclass UINavigationController, make this navigation controller be an instance of your subclass, and put `supportedInterfaceOrientations` code into your subclass.

**Note** I tried doing what you said you did, and on my machine, the navigation controller *does* perform compensatory rotation to all three standard orientations. So I don't understand why you say it is only portrait. However, the answer is still the same.

Comment: You are right. After subclassing it I did managed to rotate to landscape but if I'll add `- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}` in `ViewController` A this `ViewController` will be in portrait (while other view controllers will start in landscape) so saying "supportedInterfaceOrientations of this view controller (ViewController) are irrelevant" is half correct. Am I wrong?

Comment: `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` is irrelevant. This is not a "presentation" situation.

Comment: Regarding your note. I was talking about the orientation the view startsup with (without rotating the device). I still not fully working on my end but I'll start another question for that. Thanks.

Comment: The orientation you start up with is the *first* orientation in the plist.

Comment: How can I force one ViewController to start with landscape and another viewcontroller to start with portrait? They all act like the subclassed NavigationController

Comment: Yup that's how iOS 6 works. The navigation controller is in charge. You can't force rotation. The only way to force rotation is to use a presented view controller. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15301322/341994

Comment: I'd love if you'll take a look at my solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16316907/1578927 I'm forcing rotation without using a presented view.