# iOS6 Preferred Interface Orientation Not Working

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, autorotate

I'm trying to work with the iOS6 Auto-rotation mess.

I've looked at almost every single SO question relating to it, and no matter what I try, I can't get rotation working how I need it.

The app is using storyboards, and the layout is as follows:

`Navigation controller ---> Root view controller ---> Tab view controller ---> View controller ---> Landscape view controller.`

The view controller auto-rotates when I rotate the simulator, but when segueing back to the previous view (that is set to portrait), the view becomes landscape, when it should be portrait. If I rotate the simulator back, the view auto-rotates to portrait again, but this should've been done automatically!

I've implemented `(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation`and it doesn't get called in any view controller I put it in.

I've subclassed the NavigationController to return the `topViewController`'s `shouldAutoRotate`, `supportedInterfaceOrientations` and `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` and auto-rotation when rotating the simulator seems to work, but `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` never does its job.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: in interface builder, for each view, there is a section where you can set what it looks like in a given orientation. Have you played with that already?

Comment: Yeah, the orientations in `Simulated Metrics` are set to Portrait and Landscape as appropriate for each view.

Comment: preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation is only called for modal view controllers.

Comment: Implement the - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
 for each of the view controllers.

Comment: have you set orientations in info.plist file??

Comment: shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation doesn't get called, and I have the orientations set in the Info.plist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear Apple have removed the ability to push a view in a specific orientation. `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` does get called, but only when popping back or presenting a view controller. I had to present my landscape view rather than push it, and set `shouldAutoRotate` = NO.

Refer to: [In iOS6, trouble forcing ViewController to certain interfaceOrientation when pushed on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300819/in-ios6-trouble-forcing-viewcontroller-to-certain-interfaceorientation-when-pus) for more details.