# How to change UIViewController Orientation to UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft for one view in iOS7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, orientation, xcode5.1

I've tried the following methods to force landscape on one of my views:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
```

}

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
```

}

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
return YES;
```

}

Neither did work. Note that I'm testing on the simulator and on an iPhone

Thanks

Comment: I am using NavigationControler for pushing Views.{UINavigationController *navigationController[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:[[MiddleViewController alloc] init]];
  
   [self.window navigationController];
  return YES;

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16780545/ios6-preferred-interface-orientation-not-working

Answer (score 0):

please goto Targets in Xcode and in Generate Category select Device Orientation ticked for Landscape Orientation.