# how do I stop presented view controller from getting dimissed

Tags: ios, objective-c, presentviewcontroller, autorotate, uipresentationcontroller

I am presenting a view controller programmatically but when the device is rotated it's getting auto-dismissed.

I don't know why it happens and how do I fix it

Here is the code

```
        UINavigationController* navC  = blah blah.
        ViewContoller* vc = blah blah

        [navC  setViewControllers:@[vc]];

        // Normal case.
        if (![[[self window] rootViewController] presentedViewController]) {
            [[[self window] rootViewController] presentViewController: navC  animated:true completion:nil];
        }
```

I have kept the code in appdelegate

Any help in resolving this is appreciated

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: Please find the updated question

Comment: possibly duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25391564/ios-7-dismiss-modal-view-controller-and-force-portrait-orientation)

Comment: use setRootViewController something like that, [[self window] setRootViewController:navC];

Comment: @ElstineP, Please see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357162/how-to-force-view-controller-orientation-in-ios-8)... It may help you to solve your issue.

Comment: in app delegate in which function you are calling this method?

Comment: I mean I have the function over there to present it