# Supporting Multiple Interface but have single interface in home screen not working in iOS8 + iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, orientation, ios8, xcode6

I have view structure like below.

```
HomeView(Support only portrait mode)
 |
 |
 V
View1(Support all orientation)
 |
 |
 V
View2(Support all orientation)
```

**Problem :**
When i am `coming back from View2(Landscape mode)` to `HomeView` by calling `popToRootViewController` method,It did not call **`supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow`** method of **App_Delegate** and display
**HomeView in `landscape mode`**.

**Image:** 
[image]

**Note :**
Same thing not happens when i came back from View1(Landscape mode) to HomeView by calling popToRootViewController method
it will call supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow and all works great.
If I run app using XCode6 in iOS7 all works great.

`I read below question but it did not help me`.
[How to maintain presenting view controller's orientation when dismissing modal view controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24229677/how-to-maintain-presenting-view-controllers-orientation-when-dismissing-modal-v)

In above link `matt` said that **`iOS8 stop support for friezing orientation`**, but I did not find it in `apple document`
if you have any `reference link` about this change please share.

**Question :**
1] Why delegate method supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow is not calling.
2] Is it possible to have one view with support single orientation and all other will support all orientation.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I solve it and post answer as it will may help some one**

**Problem :**
I have below code in supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow.

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    // Suport only portrait mode for home screen
    if([self.navigationController.topViewController isKindOfClass:[ViewHome class]])

    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

But `delegate` method `supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow` not called
when use `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` method when there is`more then two view Cotnrollers`exists in stack.
**Solution :**
Step1: Create sub class of Navigation controller.

Step2: Override method popToRootViewControllerAnimated and write code as below
// Overwrite super class method popToRootViewControllerAnimated.

```
-(NSArray*)popToRootViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    // Only for iOS8 and above
    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1)
    {
        // Array which will contaimn all poped view controllers object.
        NSMutableArray *popedControllersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        // Tmp created controllers object
        NSArray *controllers;

        // Hold first view cotnrollers.
        UIViewController *firstViewController = [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];

        // Pop to first view controllers with no animation.
        controllers = [super popToViewController:firstViewController animated:NO];

        // Add poped view cotnrollers objects to the array.
        [popedControllersArray addObjectsFromArray:controllers];

        // Pop to root view controller with animation
        [super popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

        // Add first view controller object as it is poped by above line.
        [popedControllersArray addObject:firstViewController];

        // return poped view controllers object.
        return popedControllersArray;
    }
    else
    {
        // Called super view popToRootViewControllerAnimated method and return popped
        // view controllers array.
        return [super popToRootViewControllerAnimated:animated];
    }
}
```

Please fill free for any comments and ask for any questions.

Comment: Is this a change in iOS 8 that "delegate method supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow is not called when we use popToRootViewControllerAnimated method when there are more than two view controllers in navigation controller stack" ?

Comment: What i can say is, it's a bug in iOS8 it must call supprtedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow method but it did not.

Comment: I have another orientation related issue in iOS 8. It would be very helpful if you could look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357162/how-to-force-view-controller-orientation-in-ios-8?noredirect=1#comment41375612_26357162 and share your feedback.

Comment: @RashmiRanjanmallick I don't understand your question but it may help [UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation]; write it on viewDidLayoutSubviews and viewDidAppear, May help