# After the launch of iOS 8, already released app is behaving abnormally

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, orientation, ios8

As soon as I updated to iOS 8, i found that my already released app is not properly showing the orientations, my app only support landscape orientations, but when i checked it on iOS 8, the first navigation controller is in Portrait orientation.

It automatically goes fine after it goes to background, but on fresh launch it behaves in the same way.

All orientation methods are implemented properly and working fine on iOS 7 and later.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation   
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
```

Comment: Can you give your view structure i have same problem, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25769068/supporting-multiple-interface-but-have-single-interface-in-home-screen-not-worki

Comment: Navigation Controller -> ViewController -> Views

Answer (score 3):

Here it is Documentation of deprecated Method in [iOS 8 about Orientation and other Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW171)

[image]

Comment: Any suggestion what I need to do now, any new methods that need to be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

**Ok, It got Fixed**

As my App was creating `UIWindow` object before I set the Status bar orientation and It was through the `xib` so I am creating the UIWindow using code now.

```
window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

As in `iOS8` it initialize MainWindow frame according to the Device orientation. but it don't do that same with the `iOS7` and earlier.