# Swift: Enable landscape for one controller and for the rest only portrait

Tags: ios, swift, uiinterfaceorientation

My application was only in portrait mode, but I need a controller to also support landscape.

Here my info.plist:

```
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
```

And in my app delegate I have added this:

```
var shouldRotate = false

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return shouldRotate ? .allButUpsideDown : .portrait
    }
```

In my controller:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.shouldRotate = true // or false to disable rotation
    }
```

But the controller not rotate, what is my mistake? This controller is open in modal on a navigation controller

Comment: Follow this link you will get your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28243241/rotation-only-in-one-viewcontroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Past in controlllers seprately, According to your requirment.

```
override public var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return true
} 

override public var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .all
}

override public var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: UIInterfaceOrientation {
    return .all
}
```

## this should be in viewcontroller, where you want both landscape and portrait.

// other Viewcontrollers :

override public var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
return false
}

```
override public var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .portrait
}

override public var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: UIInterfaceOrientation {
    return .portrait
}
```

## // add this in viewcontroller ehere you want Application in portrait oreintation.

Enable all required orientation for whole Application.

And please remove your code in appDelegate related to orientation

Comment: This is not what I want, this code forces the landscape. I want the controller support portrait AND landscape mode.