# How to enable rotation interface orientation on a specific screen

Tags: ios, swift, uiinterfaceorientation

I have set globally portrait interface orientation in target settings.

But I would like to have all possible interface orientation on a specific view controller only.

Is there a way to do it.

I don't need force rotation to a specific ordination, I just need to enable rotation so if user will rotate device then on this specific screen I need `.all` ordinations, but for all other view controllers I need `.portrait`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rotation only in one ViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28243241/rotation-only-in-one-viewcontroller)

Comment: yea thanks works like a Sharm!