# Orientation gets change when dismissing a presented view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiinterfaceorientation

In my app, all view controllers are having Portrait orientation except one. So let's name it, "`GameViewController`". The `GameViewController` is sticked to Landscape orientation only.

This is how I'm showing it in landscape mode:

`MyViewController.m`:

> It's always in Portrait orientation, and from where we'll be presenting `GameViewController`.

```
- (void) showGameView {
    GameViewController *gameView = (GameViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GameViewController"];
    [self presentViewController:gameView animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

`AppDelegate.m`

> This is how we're maintaining Landscape orientation for`GameViewController`.

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
    if ([self.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController isKindOfClass: [GameViewController class]]) {
        GameViewController *gameView = (GameViewController *) self.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController;
        if (gameView.isPresented) {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
        } else {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
        }
    }
    else return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

> We've requirement to dismiss `GameViewController` when app goes to background.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    if(self.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController) {
        UIViewController *presentedVC = self.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController;
        if([presentedVC isKindOfClass:[GameViewController class]]) {
            GameViewController *gameView = (GameViewController *)self.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController;
            gameView.isPresented = NO;
            [gameView.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
        }
    }
}
```

`GameViewController.m`

> We're setting these to make it available in `AppDelegate`.

```
- (void) awakeFromNib {
    self.isPresented = YES;
}

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.isPresented = YES;
}

- (void) dismissView {
      self.isPresented = NO;
      [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

> Working as per expectation in following cases:

- Open App
- Open `MyViewController`
- Call `showGameView` method
- You will have a landscape orientation for `GameViewController`
- **Doesn't matters even if you would change phone to any orientation**
- Dismiss from `GameViewController`
- Will come back to Portrait orientation for `MyViewController`
- Everything looks good

> Not working as per expectation in following cases:

- Open App
- Open `MyViewController`
- Call `showGameView` method
- **Lock Phone**
- Change phone orientation to Landscape
- **Unlock phone, come back to the App**
- You will have a landscape orientation for `MyViewController`
- Dismiss from `GameViewController`
- Everything looks messed

> This is app settings to handle different orientations:

[image]

Comment: Did you try to allow just the Portrait option in the app settings?

Comment: Yes, in that case, it will not rotate to landscape, I forgot, it was thrown an exception as well. @LucaIaco

Comment: Mmm, and what if you generate orientation notification with `[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications]` just before presenting the GameViewController and then stopping it on dismiss with `[[UIDevice currentDevice] endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications]` ? Would it works?

Comment: I haven't tried that, let me try this. Thanks.

Comment: @LucaIaco, it doesn't help.

Comment: check this. it might help : http://stackoverflow.com/a/27561781/4569257