# How to forcibly rotate to portrait mode in iOS 7

Tags: xcode, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a navigation controller in my app which has 2 view controllers, VC1 & VC2.
VC1 is a table view and shows a list of videos from youtube then VC2 has UIWebview in which i have embedded youtubes code to play the video.

So in VC2 i want user to be able to go to landscape mode and watch the video in wide screen but in all the other vc's in my app are just portarit. So when the user presses the back button and comes back to VC1 i want the whole view to be rotated to portrait.

Is there a way to do this ??

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [In iOS6, trouble forcing ViewController to certain interfaceOrientation when pushed on stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300819/in-ios6-trouble-forcing-viewcontroller-to-certain-interfaceorientation-when-pus)

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is.

```
NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:orientation];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
```

This works from iOS 7.